# How can we return the css attributes of an element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of the most powerful things of jQuery is to select any item on a page like this:

```
$(".block").css("border","3px solid red");
```

How can I also get the values of the selected items like width height and top left offset?

Comment: I need to iterate more than one element by the way ?

Comment: For iterating, you can use jQuery's "each." http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each#callback

Comment: The question title doesn't make sense ("How can return..."), despite having been edited. How do I edit the question title? (Or do I not yet have a high enough reputation score to do it?)

Comment: @Nosredna, you need a reputation >= 2,000 to edit non-wiki questions/answers. See the FAQ here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130654/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`width`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/width), [`height`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height) and [`position`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/position) or [`offset`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset):

```
var elem = $(".block");
var elemWidth = elem.width();
var elemHeight = elem.height();
var elemPosition = elem.position();
var elemOffset = elem.offset();
```

For further questions, first take a look into the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var height = $(".block").css("height");
alert(height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".block").css("border","3px solid red").offset().top
$(".block").css("border","3px solid red").offset().left
```

CSS/[offset()](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset) in JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Like @Gumbo said yes you can get the height and position. If you are interested in other css attributes you get the value like this:

```
var border = $(".block").css("border")
```

But for height and width you are better off using height() and width() functions